# Get product order custom attributes in save_order_save_after observer in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to capture some product custom attributes for the item in the order in magento 2.
I tried with getAttribute() and getAttributeText(‘attribute_code’)
Please help

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code to get product attribute for product items in save_order_save_after observer in Magento 2.**

```
$orderObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderID);
$orderAllItems = $orderObj->getAllItems();
if ($orderAllItems) {
    foreach ($orderAllItems as $item) {
    $product_manufacturer = $item->getManufacturer();
    }
}
```

You can get all attribute from $item.